# spring mvc, form:select not working

Tags: spring, select, combobox, bind

I have got problem with binding some fields to the form.
My example (sorry for mistakes in code - I have written it from head)
Question is:
Can I bind form:select from class - there is Map with my data?
JSP page doesn't render dropdown list... other fields are rendered (for example: input type="text")

```
    Class FormDocument
    {
    private Map<Integer, String> docsMap;

    public Map<Integer, String> getDocsMap()
        {
        this.docsMap = new HashMap<Integer, String> ();
        this.docs.put(1, “Document01”);
        this.docs.put(2, “Document02”);
        this.docs.put(3, “Document03”);

        return docsMap;
        }

        // other setter, getters
    }
```

Jsp “formPage.jsp”:

```
    <form:form >
    <form:select path=”docsMap” items=”docsMap” />
    </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(“/formShow”)
    public String getFormPage(Model model)
    {
    model.addAttribute(“command”, new FormDocument());

    return “formPage”;
    }
```

If I add line in Controller:
model.addAtribute("docsMap", AND HERE IS Map);
It will render my select box...

Comment: The `path` is the attribute inside the FormDocument. The items is the list of items to render which is basically the collection of all items which are selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this tutorial on Spring data binding will help:

http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/session35